# Separate elements arranged like a dictionary from SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, dictionary

I have a column 'genre' like this (the datatype is varchar)

[image]

[image]

So I want to separate each element {xxxxxx} from it, I've tried `STRING_SPLIT(genres,‘}’)`, but it doesn't return the result I want.

[image]

Can anyone help me?

Comment: As per the question guide, please do not post images of code, data, error messages, etc. - copy or type the text into the question. Please reserve the use of images for diagrams or demonstrating rendering bugs, things that are impossible to describe accurately via text.

Comment: It's a JSON, use `OPENJSON()` instead.

Answer (score 0):

Manual for `OPENJSON()` : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/openjson-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16

```
SELECT
  *
FROM
  your_table
CROSS APPLY
  OPENJSON(your_table.genres)
    WITH
      (
        genre_id   INT           N'$.id'
        genre_name NVARCHAR(MAX) N'$.name'
      )
        AS genre
```